Fluent Bit as Syslog Server Alternative
We have an application deployed on AWS EKS cluster, which has a requirement of sending the application error messages to a syslog server.
Our default logs shipper is Fluent Bit, deployed as a Daemonset in the AWS EKS cluster.
Going over the official documentation of Fluent Bit,
There is an option for a Syslog input, which allows to collect Syslog messages through a Unix socket server (UDP or TCP) or over the network using TCP or UDP.
But loookin over the exsmpale in official documentation:
[SERVICE]
    Flush               1
    Log_Level           info
    Parsers_File        parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    Name                syslog
    Path                /tmp/in_syslog
    Buffer_Chunk_Size   32000
    Buffer_Max_Size     64000
    Receive_Buffer_Size 512000

[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  *

It seems that Fluent Bit,
Can't recived any Syslog traps (like for exsample: Kiwi Server), but only perfromes a tail action, on the Syslog log file (in the exsample: /tmp/in_syslog).
Did I understand correctly the official documentation?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
